# REVTex 4.2 setting reference to title footnote

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, revtex

I'm using REVTex 4.2, without the footnotes in the bibliography, and making use of the `\homepage[<text>]{URL}` macro, which allows me to set a footnote in my title linked to the bottom of the page, which activates every time I click on it, in this case to indicate the source code repository for my paper.

Later on my document I want to make a reference to this exact footnote, however if I add a `\label{<label>}` to it, when I click on it, instead of going to the bottom of the page where to footnote is, it leads to the title instead.

Adding a label was the recommended way of referencing the same footnote, and currently I see no other than that. How am I going to be able of achieving such behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch You are right I forgot about it. Here's a minimal working example of what I mean: [https://pastebin.com/NeKRTeeB](https://pastebin.com/NeKRTeeB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution which relies on the usage of `\phantomsection`.
Here's a minimal working example of such solution:

```latex
\documentclass[%
reprint,
nofootinbib,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{hyperref}  % Add hypertext capabilities
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

% footnote(s) to article title
\homepage[Website:\phantomsection\label{lb:homepage} ]{https://example.org}

\author{Author}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

sample text

\clearpage

sample text2 and reference: Footnote \ref{lb:homepage} on \autopageref{lb:homepage}

\end{document}
```

This solution was provided by the user Ijon Tichy over at Latex.org - [link to forum thread](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=34549&p=116146#p116146).